# How does this Prolog code work (Grandparent)?

Tags: prolog

If you have these facts:

```
parent(albert, bob).
parent(albert, betsy).
parent(albert, bill).

parent(alice, bob).
parent(alice, betsy).
parent(alice, bill).

parent(bob, carl).
parent(bob, charlie).
```

And then this code:

```
grand_parent(X, Y) :-
parent(Z, X),
parent(Y, Z).
```

And if you type:

```
grand_parent(carl, A)
```

Then it returns:

```
A = albert ? ;
A = alice ? ;
no
```

How does this work?
It's a bit confusing.  Especially the "Z" part.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry something messed up.  I've retyped it now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet it looks less confusing if you use better variable names:

```
grand_parent(Grandchild, Grandparent) :-
  parent(Parent, Grandchild),
  parent(Grandparent, Parent).
```

You see when you ask the query `grand_parent(carl, X)`, Prolog is going to find the definition of `grand_parent/2` and substitute `carl` for `Grandchild`. To prove this, it has to prove `parent(Parent, carl)`. Well, this succeeds once, unifying `Parent` with `bob`. The comma works like "and", so now Prolog has to prove `parent(Grandparent, bob)`. It succeeds, unifying `Grandparent` with `albert`. Prolog always searches the database in the order you supply it with facts, that's why we got Albert before we get Alice.

When you hit `;` it's like you're having a conversation with Prolog and you're saying "or?" as if to prompt it for another solution. So Prolog backs up to the last *choice point* and starts scanning forward. The last choice point was in `parent(Grandparent, bob)` so it scans forward until it finds `parent(alice, bob)` which succeeds, unifying `Grandparent` with `alice`. You ask it for another solution and it will exhaust all the possibilities with `parent(Grandparent, bob)` so it will back up to `parent(Parent, carl)`, which doesn't find any more solutions. At that point Prolog says `false` because it's out of ideas.

Hope this helps!